# Find changes in columns and feed a list

Tags: python, pandas

I need some help by optimizing the following function.
Well, now function is doing what I want, but it's implementation very basis and quiet slow.

My df looks like:

```
1    2    3    4   ...   19    20
------------------------
foo  Fou  bar  bar ...   noob  noob1
```

```
def find_changes_in_cols(df):
    df['Change_Info'] = ''
    for i in range(len(df)):
        liste = []
        if df.at[i, '1'] != df.at[i, '2']:
            liste.append('Downlink')
        if df.at[i, '3'] != df.at[i, '4']:
            liste.append('Uplink')
        if df.at[i, '5'] != df.at[i, '6']:
            liste.append('Inp')
        if df.at[i, '7'] != df.at[i, '8']:
            liste.append('Power')
        if df.at[i, '9'] != df.at[i, '10']:
            liste.append('SNR')
        if df.at[i, '11'] != df.at[i, '12']:
            liste.append('RFI')
        if df.at[i, '13'] != df.at[i, '14']:
            liste.append('UPBO')
        if df.at[i, '15'] != df.at[i, '16']:
            liste.append('DPBO')
        if df.at[i, '17'] != df.at[i, '18']:
            liste.append('VN')
        if df.at[i, '19'] != df.at[i, '20']:
            liste.append('Vect')
        
        df.at[i, 'Change_Info'] = liste  
    return df
```

As a result, I have a list with indications where changes are for each row.

Like:

```
1    2    3    4   ...   19    20     Change_Info
------------------------
foo  Fou  bar  bar ...   noob  noob1  [Downlink, Vect]
```

Comment: it would be easier to follow your goals if you could provide 1 or 2 rows from your df

Answer (score 0):

You can user a *for* loop and a *list* named status to do this:

```
status = ['Downlink', 'Uplink', 'Inp', 'Power', 'SNR', 'RFI', 'UPBO', 'DPBO', 'VN', 'Vect']

for j in range (20):
 if df.at[i, str(j+1)] != df.at[i, str(j+2)]:
  liste.append(status[j])
```